# Huge generational fishing ship loses net in Atlantic, leaves fleet

Tags: story-identification

Looking for a story title. Large fleet of generational fishing ships each troll their own particular slice of the Atlantic Ocean. One loses its net and is forced to leave the fleet and return to barely remembered land in North America. Some sort of odd, violently disciplined awaits them.

Comment: Hi there! That's some info already, but could you please take a look at [these guidelines on story-ID](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/98028), see if they trigger any more memories you could [edit] in? Perhaps the two most important - what kind of story was it (novel, short story, series), and when would it have been published? (it _is_ a written work, right?)

Comment: Also - some sort of odd, violently disciplined _what_ awaits them? I think a word is missing - or did you mean that an odd, violent discipline awaited them?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's Cyril Kornbluth's [Shark Ship](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?56943), asked about here ([Trying to find post-apocalypse short story with survivors on ship finding murder ashore](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/186293/trying-to-find-post-apocalypse-short-story-with-survivors-on-ship-finding-murder/186297#186297)) already.

Quoting myself

> The land has been taken over by a death-obsessed cult, the
> protagonists live on ships that harvest plankton and (almost) never
> touch land.
>
> By the time of the story, the land dwellers have (mostly) wiped
> themselves out (the intergenerational murder you mention is definitely
> a factor). The protagonists' ship loses its net and they face
> starvation if they don't return to the land.